# How to use if-then in regular expressions?

Tags: regex, postfix-mta

I'm writing a regular expression for Postfix that defines its virtual domains map. I want to catch all subdomains of a domain except for two.

Assuming my domain is *example.com* and the two exclusion subdomains are *in,mail*, I wrote the following regular expression:

`(?(?!mail|in).+\.example.com)`

It supposed to recognize *whatever.example.com* but not *in.example.com* or *mail.example.com*.

It does work in [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), but it doesn't work in Postfix nor Ruby. I'm assuming that I'm using if-then wrong, what is the correct syntax? Are there other options?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Ruby doesn't support conditional regexes. Not sure about Postfix. Comparison table: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html

Comment: You don't need an if/then, just a negative lookahead. The syntax is almost identical, so I don't know if Postifx is more likely to recognize it, but it's worth a try: `(?!mail|in).+\.example.com`

Comment: @Chriszuma thanks, but in this case it recognizes *ail.example.com*.

Comment: I don't follow. Both methods should recognize *ail*.

Comment: @eldarerathis if you think my regex is correct, you're welcome to write your comment as an answer and I will accept it. thanks!

Comment: @Chriszuma sorry for not being clear enough: I meant that `"mail.example.com" =~ /(?!mail|in).+\.example.com/` will match and return 1 (the position of matched string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an anchor, then it should work.

```
\b(?!mail|in).+\.example.com
```

See it [here on Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/rSBDbkbEpX)

The anchor at the beginning `\b` is a word boundary. This assures that there is non word character before your subdomain and therefor it does not match `ail` from `mail` anymore.

This matches

> www.example.com
>   whatever.example.com

and not

> mail.example.com
>   in.example.com

**UPDATE**

Probably the `^` anchor is the better choice here. This would match the start of the string.

```
^(?!mail|in).+\.example.com
```

For your examples it makes no difference, but if your URL starts with a non-word character then it would be wrong with the word boundary.

Comment: Looks like Postfix doesn't support one of the regex features you've used it here, but my question wasn't Posfix specific and you did bother to explain it so I'm accepting it. Thanks!